# tx_news: extend with a second container $contentElements

Tags: typo3, tx-news

TYPO3 8.7.4
news 6.0.0

Is it possible to extend news in a news_extend extension with a second container? (like contentElements)
The goal is to place this second container in the related content of the detail page.

Is there an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Just extend the news tca and model as described in the documentation

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's easy. You need to add field to database, configure it in TCA, extend the news model and adjust the detail template.

1. in news_extend/ext_tables.sql add:

```
    CREATE TABLE tx_news_domain_model_news (
        tx_newsextend_content_elements_second text
    );
```

2. in news_extend/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tx_news_domain_model_news.php:

```
    $newNewsColumns = [
        'tx_newsextend_content_elements_second' => [
        //      .... here copy the original 'content_elements' field's config from ext news' TCA. update the label to yours.
    ];

    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('tx_news_domain_model_news', $newNewsColumns);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('tx_news_domain_model_news', 'tx_newsextend_content_elements_second', '', 'after:content_elements');
```

3. in news_extend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf add:

```
    ...
    <trans-unit id="tx_news_domain_model_news.tx_newsextend_content_elements_second">
            <source>Additional content elements</source>
    </trans-unit>
```

4. news_extend/Classes/Domain/Model/News.php:

```
    namespace [my vendor]\NewsExtend\Domain\Model;

    class News extends \GeorgRinger\News\Domain\Model\News {

        // here copy all uses of contentElement field from original model, only name it txNewsextendContentElementsSecond.
        // watch whether it's only declared property and getter/setter (simple fields), or something more is done in the model and do it the same way as there.
        // tip: see getContentElementIdList() method

    }
```

5. register your extension as provider of news' model extending class:
   in news_extend/ext_localconf.php add:

```
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['classes']['Domain/Model/News'][] = 'news_extend';
```

6. now you can use this in your template:

```
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.txNewsExtendContentElementsSecond}">
        <!-- content elements second -->
        <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.tx_news.contentElementRendering">{newsItem.txNewsExtendContentElementsSecondIdList}</f:cObject>
    </f:if>
```

Above may not just work if you copy-paste it, I'm writing it from my notes. But it will help you to get the idea. Good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot.
I think there is a table missing (also change in the new tca):
tx_news_related_news_2 analog to tx_news_related_news.
Without this table i do not get separated the two containers.